# problems with nested python list and dictionary problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am a beginner to python.  I have a code but I can only understand some part of it..
Can you explain me the last line which calls command in detail for this problem?
Also why do we pass li:list as parameter in pop() function?

```
def insert(ls,params):
    ls.insert(int(params[0]), int(params[1]))

def print_list(ls, params):
    print(ls)

def remove(ls, params):
    ls.remove(int(params[0]))

def append(ls, params):
    ls.append(int(params[0]))

def sort_list(ls, params):
    ls.sort()

def pop(ls: list, params):
    ls.pop()

def reverse(ls, params):
    ls.reverse()

commands = {
    'insert': insert,
    'print': print_list,
    'remove': remove,
    'append': append,
    'sort': sort_list,
    'pop': pop,
    'reverse': reverse
}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input())

    ls = []

    for _ in range(N):
        cmd = input().split(' ')
        commands[cmd[0]](ls, cmd[1:])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oof, okay, let's start. I'll begin by saying that this is not idiomatic code, and is not the way any proficient Python programmer would structure their program. That said: there's merit in analyzing it.

Working backwards: let's talk about

> why do we pass li:list as parameter in pop() function

You're speaking I assume about the function declaration here

```py
def pop(ls: list, params):
    ls.pop()
```

That is called a function annotation and is documented [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/). They're often used as type hints, and the Python runtime strips them out entirely. No behavior can change from using or omitting a function annotation.

Now the meat and potatos:

> Can you explain me the last line

```py
cmd = input().split(' ')
commands[cmd[0]](ls, cmd[1:])
```

These two lines are inseparable. The first one calls `input` to ask the user what to run, then splits it on spaces to generate a list of strings. For instance that might be:

```py
# user-input: append 3 4 5 6 7
cmd == ['append', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
```

Then the next line grabs the first element of that list and looks up the command by that name, which is a function

```py
commands[cmd[0]]
```

and calls it, passing in as arguments the list itself, and the rest of the parameters from the user input

```py
                (ls, cmd[1:])
```

In my example, this results in a call that looks like:

```py
append(lst, ['3', '4', '5', '6', '7'])
```

---

If I were to rewrite this, I would question how relevant it is entirely. It seems like a lot of internals are being exposed to the user. If convinced that it was necessary, I would use `list.__getattribute__` to pair method names with those methods.

```py
# replacing all the function definitions and the "commands" dict:

def get_method(lst: list, attrname: str):
    try:
        method = lst.__getattribute__(attrname)
    except AttributeError:
        return None
```

Then split the command name from the arguments in-line, and check that the method exists before calling it.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    lst = []
    for _ in range(n):
        cmd, *args = input().split(' ')

        method = get_method(lst, cmd)
        if method is not None:
            method(*args)
```

Comment: @geekypraveen that's valid syntax, but almost certainly not what you want. That will redefine `commands['append']` to be the tuple `(lst, ['3', '4', '5', '6', '7'])` instead of the function `append`.